# How to make a python object return attribute data when called directly

Tags: python, object, call

So i want to something like this in Python:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name, self.age

p = Person('A', 20)
```

Then hope to call object p directly to get the tuple (self.name, self.age)

But as you can see when you run this program, you get the problem:

```
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

How can have this behavior?

Thanks!

Note: The problem is not specific to the tuple data type; it can be anything, like a pandas dataframe for example. I just want to return some attribute data, whatever type it is.

Comment: Do you want `(self.name, self.age)` as a string, or as an actual tuple?

Comment: Yes. I want i as an actual tuple. Not a string.

Comment: Is that the full definition of your actual `Person` class, or does it also have other methods? If you don't need methods, you could use a namedtuple, or the new dataclass.

Comment: Well this is a simplified model of my problem. It is not specific to the tuple datatype but can be anything like a dataframe for example. The importance is the concept i want to discover: How to actually return attribute data when the object is called directly (rather than returning its memory address)

Comment: @mctrjalloh Ok but what do you mean by _called directly_, what is that ?

Comment: The object `p` _doesn't_ return its memory address, when you put plain `p` in your code. Stuff like "<__main__.Person object at 0xb7227cac>" is just the default `__repr__` method, which is what you see if you try to print a `Person` instance and `Person` doesn't define its own `__repr__`.

Comment: Yes. Now how to overrite this behavior to get actual attribute data?

Comment: So the closest you're going to get is to use what chepner first suggested and make `Person` iterable, so you can do stuff like `name, age = p` or `t = tuple(p)`, or `seq = [*p]`. Etc.

Comment: `__repr__` and `__str__` are for getting a string representation of an object. You don't use them for producing non-strings, that will just make a mess.

Comment: Also, `__repr__` and `__str__` only get called if you call them explicitly, by doing some operation that tries to convert the object to a string, eg `str(p)`,  or if you try to print them (either with an explicit `print`, or by typing the object name by itself in the interactive interpreter)  since `print` will do that string conversion implicitly. They are **not** called every time you simply try to use the object.

Answer (score 5):

As the error suggest, your `__repr__` must return a string

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name + str(self.age)
```

---

Now, if your goal is to write a custom way of representing your object as a tuple, what you are looking for is `_iter__` instead,

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.name
    yield self.age

p = Person('A', 20)
print(tuple(p))
>>>>('A', 20)
```

Comment: I want to return the tuple itself, or any data that is available in the object attributes. But not the string representation. That was just an attempt.

Comment: @mctrjalloh Just want to make sure I correctly understood your problem, could you please give more detail on what you mean by _called directly_. Do you want to return a tuple when you use `p()` ?

Comment: Now let's say rather than being a tuple it was a pandas dataframe i wanted to return...

Comment: @mctrjalloh You're still not answering what you mean by _called directly_.

Comment: NO. just by typing p without the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Person` iterable:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.name
        yield self.age

name, age = p
```

Comment: Alternatively, `def __iter__(self):` `yield from (self.name, self.age)`

Comment: Depends on what you mean. A `Person` iterator yields its name and age in succession; what you do with that is a separate issue.

Comment: @mctrjalloh If you want a dataframe, why use a class at all? Just make a function that takes the args you want and returns the desired dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make the class instance callable, and return the desired tuple when called. Eg,

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person({self.name}, {self.age})'

    def __call__(self):
        return self.name, self.age

p = Person('A', 20)
print(p)
t = p()
print(t, type(t))
```

**output**

```
Person(A, 20)
('A', 20) <class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `__repr__`is supposed to return something, which looks like a valid Python expression, you may choose to implement `__str__` instead (even if this implementation would fit both purposes):

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Person({}, {})".format(self.name, self.age)
```

Update: If a tuple is actually desired, you simply have to use an non-predefined routine:

```
def get_attributes(self):
    return self.name, self.age
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on, maybe you're looking for a `namedtuple`- it would give you exactly what you're looking for:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name, age')
```

So you'd basically get a tuple every time you created a person (you'd get unpacking and such)- however, the object person will be immutable, not sure if that's what you're shooting for here.

Comment: This proposal no longer holds as soon as a real method is required, like `is_of_age()`.

Comment: Again, it depends what he's looking for. 
"Then hope to call object p directly to get the tuple (self.name, self.age)"